# Introducir en prolog nuevos hechos mediante asserta

Tags: prolog

he estado tratando de usar en mi programa tanto `asserta` como `assertz` y no para de decirme el compilador

> No permission to modify static procedure `asserta/1'

he estado leyendo otros mensajes y en teoría debería solucionarse indicando :-dynamic el problema es que aún así me sigue dando error, este es el código que he usado en un ejemplo para intentar ver porque falla.

```
prueba(abc).
prueba(123).
:- dynamic prueba/1.
asserta(prueba('666')).
```

he intentado colocando el dynamic en otro sitio, pero nada, tanto con `asserta` como con `assertz` y me da error y no se porque, he probado también quitando las comillas simples ''.

Solamente me deja con `assert` el problema es que `assert` no hace nada, al comprobar luego los hechos que hacen prueba cierto no aparece el introducido.

Preguntaba porque la verdad que me estoy bloqueando ya no se que hacer, porque cualquier ejemplo que veo, se usa el asserta en tiempo de ejecución no en el propio programa y solo se menciona el uso de dynamic sin dar un ejemplo completo.

Comment: Hola David, me alegro que encontraras la solución. Por favor, en lugar de ponerla como edición a la pregunta, ponla abajo en la sección de respuesta (si es posible con un ejemplo de cómo lo hiciste al final). Lee [ask] y [answer] para más información. Saludos.

Comment: De acuerdo, ahora mismo lo hago, no vi en su momento el mensaje por eso no lo he hecho hasta ahora

Answer (score 1):

Pongo un ejemplo de lo que hice en mi programa, por si a alguien le ocurre la misma duda, sepa cómo resolverla y tenga un ejemplo en el que basarse.

```
relacionDesconocidos(Persona1, Persona2):- asserta(sonDesconocidos(Persona1,Persona2)).
```

En este caso, es una regla que indica que si 2 personas son desconocidos, añade a las reglas, que no se conocen, básicamente es comprobar si 2 personas se conocían o no, una vez confirmamos el hecho, añadimos dicha relación, el error que puede ocurrir con `aserta`, a diferencia de `assert`, es que `assert` puede ser incluido solo. Ejemplo:

```
assert (sonDesconocidos(Persona1,Persona2)).
```

Que introduciría el hecho sin necesidad, de comprobar ninguna condición o regla.

Sin embargo con `asserta` y otras versiones de `assert`, es que deben ser parte de una regla, si no dará error. Entonces debe ser así:

```
condicion o regla:- asserta(hecho a introducir()).
```